# How to make a ruby method that deciphers a string?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, encryption, methods

I am trying to make a method that deciphers strings encrypted like this:

```
"65 119esi 111dl 111lw 108dvei 105n 97n 111ka" == "A wise old owl lived in an oak"
"84eh 109ero 104e 115wa 116eh 108sse 104e 115eokp" == "The more he saw the less he spoke"
"84kanh 121uo 80roti 102ro 97ll 121ruo 104ple" == "Thank you for all your help"
```

For each word,
the second and the last letter is switched (e.g. Hello becomes Holle) and the first letter is replaced by its character code (e.g. H becomes 72).

I came to this, its gives me two array, one with the bytes value turned into alphabetic character and another with the rest of the word characters, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to switch the second and last letter's positions and put them back together.

```
def decipher(string)
  str = string.split(" ")
  str.map do |word|
    bytes = word.match(/\d+/).to_s.to_i.chr
    words = word.gsub(/\d+/, "")
  end
end
```

There's probably better ways to do it, I'm pretty new and still learning. Thanks!

Comment: "but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to switch the second and last letter's positions" Indeed. That's the inner problem. Pretend the rest of the problem doesn't exist. Concentrate solely on strings like "oellh", "e", "pu", and write a method that deals with all of them. When you have that, the larger solution falls into your lap.

Comment: Hint: if the string is longer than two letters, then the inner part is `[1..-2]` of it. Now consider the power of `s[1..-2] = s[1..-2].reverse(); s.reverse()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use parallel assignment to swap chars like this

```rb
word[1], word[-1] = word[-1], word[1]
```

For the complete program, my way would be like this:

```rb
def cipher(string)
  string.split.map do |word|
    word[1], word[-1] = word[-1], word[1] if word.size > 1
    word[0].ord.to_s + word[1..-1]
  end.join(' ')
end

def decipher(string)
  string.split.map do |word|
    number_part = word.to_i.to_s
    word = number_part.to_i.chr + word[number_part.size..-1]
    word[-1], word[1] = word[1], word[-1] if word.size > 1
    word
  end.join(' ')
end

text = cipher('A wise old owl lived in an oak')
puts text            # 65 119esi 111dl 111lw 108dvei 105n 97n 111ka
puts decipher(text)  # A wise old owl lived in an oak
```

Comment: Lovely. answer!

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this:

```
def decipher(string)
  ints_and_chars = string.scan(/(\d+)(\S*)/)
  ints_and_chars.map { |int, chars|                               
    [int.to_i.chr, chars[-1], chars[1..-2], chars[0]].join   
  }.join(' ')
end

decipher("65 119esi 111dl 111lw 108dvei 105n 97n 111ka") 
#=> "A wise old owl lived in an oak"
decipher("84eh 109ero 104e 115wa 116eh 108sse 104e 115eokp") 
#=> "The more he saw the less he spoke"
decipher("84kanh 121uo 80roti 102ro 97ll 121ruo 104ple") 
#=> "Thank you Piotr for all your help"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do by using [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a regular expression, avoiding the need to convert the string to an array of words, modifying each word in the string and then joining the resulting array.

```
R_DECRYPT = /\d+|(?<=\d)\p{L}(?=\p{L})|(?<=\p{L})\p{L}(?!\p{L})/
```

```
def decrypt(str)
  first_ltr_idx = nil
  str.gsub(R_DECRYPT) do |s|
    i = Regexp.last_match.begin(0)
    case
    when s.match?(/\d/)
      first_ltr_idx = i + s.length
      s.to_i.chr
    when str[i-1].match?(/\d/)
      str[str.index(/\p{L}(?!\p{L})/, i+1)]
    else
      str[first_ltr_idx]
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
s1 = "65 119esi 111dl 111lw 108dvei 105n 97n 111ka"
s2 = "84eh 109ero 104e 115wa 116eh 108sse 104e 115eokp"
s3 = "84kanh 121uo 80roti 102ro 97ll 121ruo 104ple"
```

```
ds1 = decrypt(s1)
  #=> "A wise old owl lived in an oak"
ds2 = decrypt(s2)
  #=> "The more he saw the less he spoke"
ds3 = decrypt(s3)
  #"Thank you Piotr for all your help"
```

---

```
R_ENCRYPT = /(?<!\p{L})\p{L}|(?:(?<=\A\p{L})|(?<= \p{L}))\p{L}(?=\p{L})|(?<=\p{L})\p{L}(?!\p{L})/
```

```
def encrypt(str)
  second_ltr_idx = nil
  last_idx = str.length-1
  str.gsub(R_ENCRYPT) do |ch|
    i = Regexp.last_match.begin(0)
    case
    when i.zero? || str[i-1] == ' '
      second_ltr_idx = i + 1
      ch.ord.to_s
    when i == last_idx || str[i+1] == ' '
      str[second_ltr_idx]
    else
      str[str.index(/\p{L}(?!\p{L})/, i+1)]
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
encrypt(ds1) == s1
  #=> true
encrypt(ds2) == s2
  #=> true
encrypt(ds3) == s3
  #=> true
```

---

We can write the two regular expressions in *free-spacing* mode to make them self-documenting.

*R_DECRYPT written in free-spacing mode*

```
/
# Match digits at beginning of each word
\d+             # match 1+ digits
|               # or
# Match first letter of each word
(?<=\d)         # assert following match is preceded by a digit
\p{L}           # match a Unicode letter
(?=\p{L})       # assert previous match is followed by a letter
|               # or
# Match last letter of each word
(?<=\p{L})      # assert following match is preceded by a letter
\p{L}           # match a letter
(?!\p{L})       # assert previous match is not followed by a letter
/x              # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

`(?<=\d)` and `(?<=\p{L})` are *positive lookbehinds*, `(?=\p{L})` is a *positive lookahead* and `(?!\p{L})` is a *negative lookahead*.

*R_ENCRYPT written in free-spacing mode*

```
/
# Match letter at beginning of a word
(?<!\p{L})      # assert following match is not preceded by a Unicode letter
\p{L}           # match a letter
|               # or
# Match second letter of a word
(?:             # begin a non-capture class
  (?<=\A\p{L})  # Assert following match is preceded by a letter at the
                # beginning of the string
  |             # or
  (?<=[ ]\p{L}) # Assert following match is preceded by a space followed
                # by a letter (space is in character class for protection
 )              # end non-capture group
\p{L}           # match a letter
(?=\p{L})       # Assert previous match is followed by a letter
|               # or
# Match last letter of a word
(?<=\p{L})      # Assert following match is preceded by a letter
\p{L}           # match a letter
(?!\p{L})       # Assert previous match is not followed by a letter
/x              # Invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

`(?<!\p{L})` is a *negative lookbehind*.